How to add value to nested jsonb array
I have a jsonb value of approximate structure:
'{
    "a": {
        "result": 10,
        "values": [
           {"date": "2024-11-10", "question": 5},
           {"date": "2024-11-11", "question": 10}
        ]
    }
}'

I need to add another object to the "values" ​​array:
{"date": "2024-11-12", "question": 1}

Expected result:
'{
    "a": {
        "result": 10,
        "values": [        [
           {"date": "2024'-11-10", "question": 5},
           {"date": "2024'-11-11", "question": 10},
           {"date": "2024'-11-12", "question": 1}
        ]
    }
}'

How to achieve this in Postgres?

Please tag the question with the version of PostgreSQL that is being used. JSON functions have evolved and expanded with newer versions.

This is not a duplicate of the suggested prior answer - which asks to add an object to a JSON value stored as text, i.e. that other question is a mess. And John's new answer here is also clearly better than anything offered over there.

There are several ways to achieve the described results. One method is to use JSONB_INSERT to append to the values array.
WITH
  t (test_value) AS (
    VALUES
      ('{
          "a": {
            "result": 10,
            "values": [
              {
                "date": "2024-11-10",
                "question": 5
              },
              {
                "date": "2024-11-11",
                "question": 10
              }
            ]
          }
        }'::JSONB
      )
  )
SELECT
  JSONB_INSERT(
    t.test_value,
    '{a, values, -1}',
    '{"date": "2024-11-12", "question": 1}',
    TRUE
  )
FROM
  t;

The call to JSONB_INSERT is used to find the values array and insert the new JSONB object after the last element (look in Table 9.49. JSON Processing Functions for a description of JSONB_INSERT).
The result is:
{
  "a": {
    "result": 10,
    "values": [
      {
        "date": "2024-11-10",
        "question": 5
      },
      {
        "date": "2024-11-11",
        "question": 10
      },
      {
        "date": "2024-11-12",
        "question": 1
      }
    ]
  }
}

This approach should work in all currently supported versions of PostgreSQL (tested with v16 and v17).
